# Game Buttons for HTML5 Moblie controls

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am trying to add buttons so when my game is on mobile it will be easy to play on the touch screen phones. I just want to add the four Arrow keys on the screen. Whats the fastest/simplest way to do this using HTML5 and/or Javascript?

I made Snake via HTML5 and Javascript. Need onscreen buttons for mobile and it can be for desktop too

Comment: Are you asking how to display HTML elements only on specific devices, or how to convert mouse clicks into keyboard clicks? If it's the second one, there is no universal way, we need to know how is your game integrated into the page. Is it Javascript based, a Java applet, some other kind?

Comment: This looks like a promising API you could use https://github.com/austinhallock/html5-virtual-game-controller

Comment: Its a simple snake game to test this whole thing out :)